# why I can not see the video when I run cheese not by sudo

Tags: cheese, 21.10

When I run cheese not by sudo, I can not see the video. Why?[image]

Comment: Can you add `getfacl /dev/video*` to your question please?

Comment: Also, open the menu -> preferences, and check if any camera is detected there.

Comment: You may have used `sudo <graphical application>  too frequently lately. Doing this can change permissions under the home directory of the user, and lead to issues such as this. Temporarily create a new account, and run cheese there. If it works in a new account, then likely something like this will be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/video"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.